# Maximum movement speed sprite PIXI.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm writing a simple game in which a user can move around a sprite. By clicking the stage, the sprite moves towards that location. The problem I'm facing is that I want to set a speed for this sprite. I do not know the values the user is going to click. I can't think of a way in which the sprite's speed is always the same.

The thing with PIXI.js is that you can set the x and y movement speed of the sprite. I want the result of those movement speeds to always be the same, for example 5. So if the sprite moves down, the y-speed would be 5. When the sprite is moving diagonally, the diagonal speed should be 5. I currently use this script, but the solution I came up with does not completely work, as the speed differs for each time I click.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

```
var Container = PIXI.Container,
autoDetectRenderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer,
loader = PIXI.loader,
resources = PIXI.loader.resources,
Sprite = PIXI.Sprite;

var stage = new PIXI.Container(),
renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(1000, 1000);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

PIXI.loader
  .add("rocket.png")
  .load(setup);

var rocket, state;

function setup() {

  //Create the `tileset` sprite from the texture
  var texture = PIXI.utils.TextureCache["animal.png"];

  //Create a rectangle object that defines the position and
  //size of the sub-image you want to extract from the texture
  var rectangle = new PIXI.Rectangle(192, 128, 32, 32);

  //Tell the texture to use that rectangular section
  texture.frame = rectangle;

  //Create the sprite from the texture
  rocket = new Sprite(texture);
  rocket.anchor.x = 0.5;
  rocket.anchor.y = 0.5;
  rocket.x = 50;
  rocket.y = 50;
  rocket.vx = 0;
  rocket.vy = 0;

  //Add the rocket to the stage 
  stage.addChild(rocket);

  document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    x = event.clientX - rocket.x;
    y = event.clientY - rocket.y;
    rocket.vmax = 5;
    var total = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
    var tx = x/total;
    var ty = y/total;
    rocket.vx = tx*rocket.vmax;
    rocket.vy = ty*rocket.vmax;
    });

  state = play;
  gameLoop();
}

function gameLoop() {

  //Loop this function at 60 frames per second
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  state();

  //Render the stage to see the animation
  renderer.render(stage);
}

function play(){
    rocket.x += rocket.vx; 
    rocket.y += rocket.vy;
}
```

Comment: @Jonasw And how would that solve the problem? Then the sprite would go horizontally with a speed of 5, no matter where I click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? This would normalize x and y.

```
var total = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

and it looks x and y are missing 'var'.

```
var x = event.clientX - rocket.x;
var y = event.clientY - rocket.y;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks! Should've used pythagoras indeed.